# BDAT support for Postfix

Tags: postfix, smtp

Any idea whether Postfix supports BDAT command?

I get this error:

> 550 5.6.11 SMTPSEND.BareLinefeedsAreIllegal; message contains bare linefeeds, which cannot be sent via DATA and receiving system does not support BDAT

I couldn't find much info about this, will it be supported in future?

Comment: Can you use CR-LF ("\r\n") instead of bare LF ("\n") in your sending script/program?

Comment: I learnt that O365 is sending this request to my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Major changes with snapshot 20180805-nonprod

Preliminary support for RFC 3030 CHUNKING (BDAT) without BINARYMIME.
The Postfix SMTP server is the only program that knows the difference
between mail that was received with BDAT or DATA.

In both cases, the Postfix SMTP server will use smtpd_data_restrictions
and smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions, it will send one Milter DATA event
per mail transaction, and it will send one DATA command ending in
. to an smtpd_proxy_filter. There is no difference
in the Postfix queue file content.

Comment: Thanks Ralf.  One question i have is whether BDAT support is mandatory for certain email types?   If postfix does not advertise BDAT/Chunking/BinaryMime capability (on EHLO command), why would O365 still try to use these commands?

Comment: It's not mandatory... I'd guess it's an error in o365's SMTP client.